# Formatted SD Card as internal storage

Tags: lenovo, adoptable-storage, formatting

I formatted my SD card in my Lenovo Tab 4 as internal storage in order to free storage etc, but then realised how I can no longer read the card on my computer.

Is there any way to either have the computer read this SD card or to download files onto it?

Or at least can I unformat it?
Thanks so much

Comment: Have you formatted it as portable storage or internal storage?

Comment: Internal storage

Comment: You can connect your phone via USB to a PC an access the storage. Alternatively if you want to reverse the format as internal storage process see [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/188988/2241).

Comment: Hey thanks for taking time, but just whenever I connect it to the PC the device doesn't even come up (whether in a phone/tablet or even a SD reader) so I assume the computer can't read it.

Comment: Make sure you are using an USB cable that can be used for data transfer (some only allow charging). Use a recent OS (Windows 8.1 or 10 or a recent Linux distro on a PC). And when connecting the phone via USB make sure to unlock (enter PIN/password) on lock-screen first. A locked phone can not be accessed. On Windows check device manager if there are devices with yellow exclamation mark (missing driver).

Answer (score 0):

Windows computer can read FAT formatted SD card.

Lenovo tab 4 has nougat operating system. This tab's formatted card should read by computer. You can reformat sd card and connect it to computer. If card is write protected then you can not able to read it.

Look inside devices and drive. Right click on card and format it.
[image]

Comment: Hi there, Im having a problem that whenever I plug it in, the device won't even come up (if I insert my tablet with the sd card inside it'll say "Windows has picked up a non recognised device" and if in a SD card reader an empty reader will come up), do you have any advice for that?